# Java Point class move() vs setLocation()

Tags: java, point

I want to know if there is any significant difference between the java awt Point class' move(int, int) function and their setLocation(int, int) function. Does one of them run any faster or have some crazy different functionality in the background. They seem to do the exact same actions just one has a shorter name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are same. Here is what 'move' does

```
public void move(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

and here is what 'setLocation' does

```
public void setLocation(int x, int y) {
    move(x, y);
}
```

It just calls move method. 'move' accepts only integer arguments whereas 'setLocation' accepts integer, double and point type arguments.

Comment: i find it funny that they make two or more redundant functions and then use one function in the other.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a question about an API, it is best to start by reading the documentation for it.

> public void move(int x, int y)
>
> Moves this point to the specified location in the (x,y) coordinate plane. This method is identical with setLocation(int, int).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html#move(int,%20int)

I suppose you could say one difference is that `setLocation` is overloaded, allowing it to accept a `Point`, two ints, or two doubles, while `move` only accepts two ints.

Comment: I did look at the documentation, I wanted to know more about the guts. From the documentation that information is obvious